# tensorflow EarlyStopping check point to save best model on many trainning itteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback

I train a model on a huge set of data, too big for my memory.
So I load chunk of my data set, and loop on this chunks on the trainning operation one at time.

for exemple:

```
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='blabla.h5', 
                                                monitor='val_loss', 
                                                mode='min', 
                                                save_best_only=True)

for file_nb in range(100000):

    data = pd.read_csv('a_path/to/my/datas/files' + str(file_nb))
    history = model.fit(x=data[:,:3], y = data[:, -1] , calbacks=checkpoint)
```

The question: If I use ModelCheckpoint, it will save the best epoch of the last chunk used in trainning or it is able to know if on the previous chuncks trainned before, there is a better one?

If it saved only the best one of the actual chunck in trainning, there is a way to consider the previous itteration to keep the real one best trainning epoch?

Comment: Can you post your code to understand how you are feeding the data

Comment: #keerthitheja S.C. done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, [ModelCheckpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) callback monitors specified metric where the metric improves on given criteria. It saves the model weights for the current chunk where the monitored metric reaches its better `mode`(min/max) value as defined.

`ModelCheckpoint` callback is capable of recognizing improvement in performance across all chunks, not just within the last chunk and saves the best epoch seen throughout the entire training process.

**For example, Please see the below screen shot:**

[image]

Model was last improved at Epoch 7 and `ModelCheckpoint` saved it's weight at Epoch 7 then again it improves better than Epoch 7 at the Epoch 10 and it overwrites the last saved weights to save the best_weights at Epoch 10 by checking throughout the training process. You can reverify this by reloading the saved `ModelCheckpoint` weights and evaluate it with test data which shows same performance as at the time of training.

(Please find the replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/b14972eaf9ab99bad15560fb58c8225f/76114767.ipynb) here for your reference.)